# Cesar cipher coding

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing code to encrypt a word in python using Cesar Cipher. I have a small error for the last two lines:

```
UnboundLocal error: Local variable codeword referenced before assignment
```

I am new to Python and still not familiar with this type of errors.

I should be able to allow the user to enter a word to encrypt or decrypt and the program will perform the process based on the user choice.

```
def main():
  #take user word and pass it to the function to encrypt it
  userinput=str(input("Enter the word to encrypt:"))
  UserInput = userinput.upper()
  print("You entered:",UserInput)
  key=int(input("Enter the key shift:"))
  sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key) #send the word for incryption
  
def sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key):
  coded_char=0
  for each in UserInput:
    if each=='A': 
      coded_char=65+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='B': 
      coded_char=66+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='C': 
      coded_char=67+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='D': 
      coded_char=68+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='E': 
      coded_char=69+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='F': 
      coded_char=70+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='G': 
      coded_char=71+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='H': 
      coded_char=72+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='I': 
      coded_char=73+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='J': 
      coded_char=74+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='K': 
      coded_char=75+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='L': 
      coded_char=76+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='M': 
      coded_char=77+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='N': 
      coded_char=78+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='O': 
      coded_char=79+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='P': 
      coded_char=80+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='Q': 
      coded_char=81+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='R': 
      coded_char=82+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='S': 
      coded_char=83+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='T': 
      coded_char=84+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='U': 
      coded_char=85+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='V': 
      coded_char=86+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='W': 
      coded_char=87+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='X': 
      coded_char=88+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='Y': 
      coded_char=89+key
      jointfun(coded_char)
    elif each=='Z': 
      coded_char=90+key
      #if coded_char>90 #<<-- I will work on this later to make the iteration once the code exceed 90
        #rem=coded_char-90
      jointfun(coded_char)
    
def jointfun(coded_char):
  str (codedword)

  codedword = ''.join((codedword,coded_char))
  print("The coded word is:", codedword)
```

Comment: Even without the error, `str (codedword)` alone wouldn't do anything.

Comment: What is the statement `str (codedword)` supposed to do? Why did you include that?

Comment: I am trying to append the new coded number to a list, and then I would use each coded number to find its character equivalence, then print the new coded word.

Comment: FYI - if you think you need to write an if statement with 26 if/elifs, there's almost always going to be a better way. In this case it might help you to know that `ord("A")` == 65, etc.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBuck - Can you post me a link to a resource of ord("A") == 65? I am new to Python and need to read about it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord - At the moment you're checking every character one by one and adding its integer equivalent, but `ord(each)` will tell you that integer equivalent without needing 26 ifs.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBuck - Just found what you mean...This is really helpful :)

Comment: Dodee: `ord("A")` == 65 because `"A"` is a printable [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) character.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for your help - I am answering my question with the working programme

```
def main():
#take user word and pass it to the function to encrypt it
  userinput=str(input("Enter the word to encrypt:"))
  UserInput = userinput.upper()
  print("You entered:",UserInput)
  key=int(input("Enter the key shift:"))
  sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key) #send the word for incryption
  
def sendtoincrypt(UserInput,key):
  coded_char=[]
  newcode=0
  for each in UserInput:
    x=ord(each)
    newcode=x+key
    coded_char.append(newcode)
  displaycodednum(coded_char)
    
def displaycodednum(coded_char):
  print("The coded number is:", coded_char)
  processcodedword(coded_char)

def processcodedword (coded_char):
  coded_word=[]
  # for i, c in enumerate('test'):
   #print i, c
  for each, c in enumerate(coded_char):
    #y = chr(65)
    y=chr(c)
    coded_word.append(y)
  displaycodedword(coded_word)

def displaycodedword(coded_word):
  print("The coded word is:",*coded_word, sep='')
```